# error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::future<_Result>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, future

I am getting there is no acceptable conversion error because it seems the return value of Submit is not what I expect.

Here's a simple reproduceable

```
template<typename Task>
std::future<typename std::invoke_result<Task()>::type> Submit(Task task)
{
 
    std::future<typename std::invoke_result<Task()>::type> result;
    return result;

}
struct Mystruct
{
    std::vector<std::future<int>> Futures;
    int MyFunc(int i) { return i; };
    void Run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)

        { // i tried bind and lambda 
            Futures[i] = Submit(std::bind(&Mystruct::MyFunc, this, i));
            Futures[i] = Submit([this, i]() {return this->MyFunc(i); });
        }
    }

};
```

Shouldn't `std::invoke_result<Task()>::type` be an int?? because MyFunc returns an int, I expect `std::future<typename std::invoke_result<Task()>::type>`  to be converted to `std::future<int>`, so can someone explain what's going on!!

Comment: Should be either `invoke_result<Task>` or `result_of<Task()>`, they are [different](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of).

Comment: I see what I did wrong, Thanks